# How to use DEoptim in J/addon/math

Tags: j

I am trying to find the global maxima of a function and have found this package in j. However, after reading through the examples in demo I did not know how to use it yet. Anyone who can give an example about how to find the optimized parameters in a multi-parameter function, such as the function written below? I appreciate what you will do.

[image]

given that epsilon are data points given, omega and alpha have the range between 0 and 1.

Comment: Assuming that the function above is the one you want to maximise, the first step is to code it in J with input arguments for omega and alpha. This will become your objective function as per the examples in the test script. You mention above that you've looked through the demo. If you haven't looked at the examples in the [test script](http://www.jsoftware.com/wsvn/addons/trunk/math/deoptim/test/test_deoptim.ijs), that may be simpler to understand.